# Why is Nf6 a blunder here?

Tags: analysis, strategy, theory, evaluation

[image]

With Nf6, I'm trying to bring my Knight out. If the Bishop takes it, I can take the Bishop with by g7 pawn. Why is this a blunder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because after `Bxf6 gxf6` there is `Qxf6`, which wins a pawn, threatens the rook and threatens mate on f7. You can castle, but then the king is exposed by the missing g pawn. Your only other option is `Rf8`.